# ASIO io_service do not process post handlers on second run() call

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to be able to post group of handlers to `boost::asio::io_service` and then run all of them. When all handlers finished, I want to add a new group of them and `run()` again. And repeat this forever in one thread.

But I have a problem that after the first `run()` call, next posted jobs are ignored.

Here is a small example ([coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/590af0dade0d2b44)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;

    io.post([]{ std::cout << "Hello";});
    io.run();
    io.post([]{ std::cout << ", World!" << std::endl; });
    io.run();
}
```

It will print "*Hello*" message only and then successfully exit.

Why this example does not print "Hello, World!"?

Boost version: 1.71.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call [restart](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload1.html):

> A normal exit from the run() function implies that the io_context
>   object is stopped (the stopped() function returns true). Subsequent
>   calls to run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() will return
>   immediately unless there is a prior call to restart().

```
io.post([]{ std::cout << "Hello";});
io.run();
io.post([]{ std::cout << ", World!" << std::endl; });
io.restart(); // just here
io.run();
```